# Busybox ip show neighbors with MAC address

Tags: linux, networking, busybox

I am trying to find the MAC address of default gateway in busybox, my linux command like 
"ip -6 neigh show" is NOT working. ip -family inet6  route on busy box is NOT showing MAC address. How would I get the MAC address of my default gateway in busy box?

Answer (score 0):

for the IP address:

```
# ip -6 addr show
```

for gateway:

```
# ip -6 route show
```

and for the MAC adresses

```
# ip -6 neighbour show
```